What is the best collation for json data?
When converting my database to uftmb4 I noticed some columns were using utf8mb3_bin, and my command just altered them to utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci instead of utf8mb4_bin.
Why ? And also which one is better for json data that doesn't need to be sorted?
I can't find any definitive answer in the internet, and other questions here even suggest that it defaults to bin so what to use?
Using mariadb 10.11.7


And also which one is better for json data that doesn't need to be sorted?

JSON isn't a type of data, it's a format of the data. So collation has nothing to do with the fact the data is formatted as JSON.
